# Python Apply function not working in dataframe loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The funcion below are not working.
How can I use apply method on this ?

When I use the function below in this dataframe works, however when i try to use the same function in my df throw the message : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

dict = {'created_at':['Sat May 23 02:02:37 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:03:06 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:03:21 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020'],
        'text': ['Não conheço um eleitor do Bolsonaro que viu o','6 Bolsonaro se apresente neste momento dessa','eta que a nota de repudio pra isso aqui vai se', '573124: Segunda-feira vai está lambendo as b','Durante a reunião, Bolsonaro externou sua in']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

def tradutor(text):

    translator = Translator()
    eng = translator.translate(text, src = 'pt', dest='en')

    return eng.text

df['eng'] = df.text.apply(tradutor)
```

Comment: you should add `axis=1`

Comment: Also, you should move `translator` outside of the function. You don't need to create the translator every time you call the function.

Comment: works fine for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead `apply`. `map` is way more faster than `apply`.

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

dict = {'created_at':['Sat May 23 02:02:37 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:03:06 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:03:21 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020','Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020'],
        'text': ['Não conheço um eleitor do Bolsonaro que viu o','6 Bolsonaro se apresente neste momento dessa','eta que a nota de repudio pra isso aqui vai se', '573124: Segunda-feira vai está lambendo as b','Durante a reunião, Bolsonaro externou sua in']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

def tradutor(text):

    translator = Translator()
    eng = translator.translate(text, src = 'pt', dest='en')

    return eng.text

df['eng'] = df.text.map(tradutor)
```

```
created_at  text    eng
0   Sat May 23 02:02:37 +0000 2020  Não conheço um eleitor do Bolsonaro que viu o   I do not know a Bolsonaro voter who saw the
1   Sat May 23 02:03:06 +0000 2020  6 Bolsonaro se apresente neste momento dessa    6 Bolsonaro is present at the moment that
2   Sat May 23 02:03:21 +0000 2020  eta que a nota de repudio pra isso aqui vai se  eta that rejection note to this here will
3   Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020  573124: Segunda-feira vai está lambendo as b    573124: Monday will is licking the b
4   Sat May 23 02:04:32 +0000 2020  Durante a reunião, Bolsonaro externou sua in    During the meeting, expressed his Bolsonaro in
```